# Identification a Symbol for P&ID's Standards

Tags: process-engineering, instrumentation, pi-diagram

i have a question regarding on PID standards [ISO 14617](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piping_and_instrumentation_diagram). Below is the attached symbol graphic, i seem cannot find anywhere what actually this symbol refer to from standards that i have looked up; PIP, ISO, DIN and BS.
I would appreciate if anyone could clarify this to me and also it would be great to have a website or anything on where i could refer for more information about standards.

Thank you

so here i attached the diagram, i did lookup to https://www.edrawsoft.com/pid/images/pid-legend.pdf

it says triangle separator, [image]

so here is the diagram that i refer to
[image]

[image]

Comment: It would help if you posted the context. i.e. the rest of the diagram. As mark says it might be a one way valve or a diode depending on the context

Comment: the line is indeed a pipe, yes? what's the medium? specific industry?

Comment: Thank you for your replies, i already add a diagram that i refer to, yeah it is a pipe. This is closed loop cooling water if i not mistaken.

Comment: I doubt it's a separator, a separator should have one mass flow in and two out. Also note that the other symbol for triangle separator looks like a pipe expansion/reduction and also  shows up in the diagram where you would expect such a thing. Look if you find a check valve somewhere in the diagram, pressure side of a pump is a good place to look.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess it's a non-standard symbol for a check valve.  @NMech is correct that it looks like a diode, but that would not appear on a P&ID.  A check valve is a fluid flow equivalent of a diode though. I did find a reference that shows that symbol as a check valve [here](https://hardhatengineer.com/valve-symbols-pid-ball-relief-valve/).

Comment: Exactly what I thought. yet the 'VS9' next to the symbol got me puzzled.

Comment: @Algo - It's hard to tell, but I interpreted that note as "V59" - valve number 59.  As NMech suggests, seeing more of the diagram would help understand the context.

Comment: I think numering schemes like <letters + numbers for plant area/functional group> <letters denoting component type ><individual numbers> are common, so valve 59 or stop valve 9 seems plausible.

Comment: but this is guessing around somthing the op could esily answer.

Comment: Thank you guys for replying, yeah it does look like a diode. Im sorry, so already add an attachment for more diagram. V59 is the number of the valve but could not identify whether it is a standard symbol or not.

Answer (score 0):

In process engineering, you may use it as a check valve, although the most common used symbol for check valves is:

[image]

The symbol in the OPis most commonly used in electronic diagrams, and it is used to describe a diode  (there is such think as a VS9 diode [datasheet](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/348/vs9v0ua1lamtr-e-1871822.pdf)).

Comment: Thank you for your replies, it is a PID not a electronic diagram. Therefore it is not diode, sorry for not giving a bigger diagram for this. It is a valve, but don't know what kind of valve is this and whether it comply to a standard.